Dealing with Two-Item Factors in CFA
I am setting up a latent variable model for a CFA in lavaan (R), with plans to use the measurement model in a subsequent SEM analysis. The model includes five correlated factors, each with 3-4 indicator items.
One item from a factor with only three indicators does not load significantly on the latent factor, and since it's not theoretically justified to load on another factor, I removed it. As a result, one factor now has only two items, leading to identification issues in R. A possible solution would be to constrain the factor loadings of the two items to be equal.
My questions are:

What are the implications of setting equal factor loadings for interpreting the CFA?

Can I use this model in the SEM analysis with caution, or should I consider dropping the factor entirely?



In the two-indicator factor model, you can, in theory, estimate: 1 factor variance, 2 factor loadings, and 2 residual variances. However, since you only have 2 indicators, estimating only 3 parameters for the model to be identified is possible [using the formula $\frac{p(p+1)}2 $ to calculate the total number of parameters that can be estimated from the model, where p is the number of indicators]. This means you must fix/constrain 2 parameters.
As you mentioned, you could constrain the factor loadings to equality (estimate only a single value for both loadings), but you would also have to constrain, for instance, the factor variance to 1 in order for the model to be identified. In this model, you would estimate: 1 factor loading value and 2 residual variance values.
An alternative is to fix both factor loadings to 1 so that you are estimating the factor variance and 2 residual variances. This approach might work better since you presumably want to test structural relations at the factor level.
You can then use this factor in an SEM.

In case you missed: I edited your post with a (very) minor change in formatting. CV is $\LaTeX$ (Mathjax) enabled which you may use in your future posts. For a quick guide, check this MetaCV thread.

Also, in case you didn't like the edit, feel free to undo that!

It is no problem per se to have a factor with only two indicators (and unequal loadings) as long as that factor is non-zero correlated (or in a non-zero regression relationship) with at least one other observed variable or latent factor in the model. The loadings need not be set equal for identification unless the factor is uncorrelated with all other variables in the model.
Setting loadings equal implies (essential) tau equivalence in the sense of classical test theory. This means you would assume that the two items are measured on the same scale with the same units of measurement. This may or may not be reasonable--but it is likely not required for model identification in your case.
See also my Youtube video on this topic: Factor Model with only 2 Indicators???.

Christian, I edited your post adding the title of your video.

Thank you, I appreciate it!
